# can I debug my cpp code using linux gdb? if yes how can I keep break points on a function which is called over an object

Tags: c++, gdb

example:

```
class test_gdb
{
    public:
        void testFun(void)
        {
            cout << "this is test function"<<endl;
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    test_gdb testObj;
    testObj.testFun();
}
```

here if I want to keep a break point at testFun, how can I do it. I tried but with break testFun but it didn't work.

Comment: `testFun` is not a function, it's a method - so it is scoped to the class it is defined in. You must use the full scoped name `break test_gdb::testFun` to achieve what you want.

Comment: @A.Monti Why did you not make that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I do it

Several ways:

```
(gdb) break test_gdb::testFun
```

Set breakpoints on all `testFun`s, regardless of which class they are defined in:

```
(gdb) rbreak testFun
```

If you have several `testFun`s with different signatures (different parameter types), you can use GDB tab-completion to select one

```
(gdb) break 'test_gdb::testFun<TAB>  # GDB will complete or offer multiple choice
```